# convert multiple currencies to usd without using vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to convert multiple currencies(AUD, JPY, EUR...) into USD.

The exchange rates table includes the rate of "AUD/USD" "USD/JPY"...

Because USD are not always in denominator of the exchange rate, so I can not simply multiply the rate by foreign currencies.

I wonder if I can use range intersections to convert them. I am not sure about the formula of the range intersection.

The data is look like this:

```
TABLE 1                   Table 2   SALARY  Currency    
Currency    rate              AA    10000   AUD 
EUR/USD     1.1438            BB    80000   JPY 
USD/JPY     111.807           CC    7600    EUR 
GBP/USD     1.3022            DD    9000    GBP 
USD/CAD     1.2979            EE    7000    AUD 
AUD/USD     0.7704            ff    50000   JPY
```

Comment: "Is there a formula other than VLOOKUP" - what is your problem with it? What else do you need? Could you please post some sample data to help us understanding your issue?

Comment: can you show an example of your Data and how to show the result

Comment: Adjust your exchange table to use USD?

Comment: There is a list of employees' salaries paid in different currencies. Let's say Mike earned 10000AUD and Jackie earned 80000JPY....The exchange rate are AUD/USD and USD/JPY. I wonder how I can convert the list of foreign currencies to USD without using VLOOKUP. Thank you.

Comment: There are over 300 employees records on the list, so I can not calculate them one  by one.

Comment: again, please share some sample data, to help us understanding how your data is organized. You can edit your data e.g. [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to be properly formatted as table. Please edit your question instead of answering in comments.

Comment: Again: why do you want to avoid VLOOKUP? Seems to be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: VLOOKUP can do this for your very simply. As mentioned several times, please provide sample data and we will construct the formula you need.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table of Currency:

```
Column A        Column B Column C
    Currency    Rate    Rate in USD
    AUD         0.77    0.77          =B2
    JPY         112.32  0.008903134   =1/B3
    GBD         1.3     1.3
    EUR         1.14    1.14
    CAD         1.2979  =1/B6 (1/1.2979)
```

Near the employee list create the following:

```
           Column G       Column H
Employee    Currency      Salary    USD Salary
Mike        AUD           10000     7700     =H2*INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(G2,$A$2:$A$5,0))
Jacky       JPY           80000    712.2507
```

Under USD Salary write the formula:

```
=H2*INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(G2,$A$2:$A$5,0))
```

H2 is the salary in currency (initial)
G2 is the currency
C2:C5 the USD rate in Currency table change it to correspond your Currency data
A2:A5 The currency code change it to correspond your Currency table